# Save MKOverlay objects in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, mkmapview, mkoverlay

I have a large `MKOverlay` that I would like to be saved in `Core Data` so that I don't have to create it later. Since this isn't one of the types that you can choose in `Core Data`, how do I go about saving it?

Do I need to somehow encode it first?

Do I then need to decode it when using?

What kind of object do I select in `core data` when creating a new property?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not need to query for different overlays and you're not using core data elsewhere in your project, then you're probably better off caching the overlay on disk as an encoded NSArray.

However, if you're already using Core Data or you're caching multiple overlays then you can encode/decode the overlay in a field of type NSData. Add additional fields to the entity so you can query for the specific overlay you're looking for.

In iOS 5, you can enable optional storage of NSData fields in an external file by selecting the "Allows External Storage" option. Core Data will apply a size-based heuristic to determine if a blob or external file will result in better performance.

MKOverlay conforms to NSCoding, so you can encode and decode an entire array of MKOverlay objects using an encode method of NSKeyedArchiver and store the result in a binary field in your entity. You'll likely want + (NSData *)archivedDataWithRootObject:(id)rootObject on NSKeyedArchiver and + (id)unarchiveObjectWithData:(NSData *)data on NSKeyedUnarchiver

See the Archives section in the Archives and Serializations Programming guide for details of creating a keyed archive at: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/archives.html

You can write a custom accessor for the entity's binary field that encodes and decodes the overlay array for you. Another option is to create a value transformer that encapsulates the encoding and decoding operations. The end result would be an overlays array property that you can set and read via entity.overlays.

Comment: While you want to cache an entire group of overlays, I'd also note it's possible to use a value transformer to store individual Objective-C class instances as core data entities. See http://petermcintyre.com/topics/uiimage-in-core-data/ for an example using UIImages

Comment: Yes, I am using Core Data across my project.  It relies heavily on it.  What I am still confused about his how to encode my MKOverlay as NSData. Have looked at the apple docs but still not very clear.

Comment: Updated original answer with encoding and decoding details.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use Apple's [`NSCoding`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) libraries to convert the object to and from a serialized state.  However, Core Data may support saving objects, but `NSCoding` lets you save any class that implements it *anywhere*, including a string sent to a server, a file written to disk, or if you're as bad a programmer as me, an `NSUserDefaults` entry.

edit- You may have to implement `NSCoding` into your own class based on `MKOverlay` by adding read and write methods, I'm uncertain.

Comment: Ok, and would this just be an NSManagedObject type in core-data?

Comment: It would seem so.  I haven't used CoreData so I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Why not instead save the properties (size, color, coordinates, etc can all be described with NSNumbers and those can be stored in Core Data natively) and recreate the MKOverlay when needed. I think that's a much more efficient approach to be honest. I'm not sure how much of an impact creating an object has, so prove me wrong if I'm wrong.

Comment: Henri, I am already doing this and then create the MKOverlays on the fly for the user. But when an overlay has about 2000 locations it might take a few seconds to load, which I want to eliminate.  Do you think that I won't get any speed benefits from saving the MKOverlay object that is already built?

Comment: Are the thousands visible at once on the screen? You could simplify the overlay depending on the zoomlevel or if it's only partially visible, there was this example code from Apple (earthquake map or something).

Comment: These are not place marks or annotations, this is an Overlay which is created from coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the large dataset that composes the overlay and turn those individual data nodes into NSManagedObjects to be stored in CoreData.

I mean, you probably COULD just NSCoder the entire thing into one giant datablob, but at that point, you might as well just write the thing to a flat file (which frankly might be better if all you want to do is read/write it without changing it).

Don't use Core Data unless you're going to be doing legit querying or piecemeal changes to the dataset.

Comment: Jasconius, in your last sentence, did you mean that for large datasets, it might take a long time to return them?

Comment: Yes, I don't want to change it once it is written, but I just need fast retrieval rather than looping through thousands of coordinates to create it when the users wants to see it. Do you think it is a better idea to write it to a flat file or to core data?  Which would be faster?

Comment: If your data is just scalar types, then I don't see how on earth Core Data could be faster than just doing a flat file with NSCoder. Even if it IS faster, the difference should be minimal, and NSCoder is far easier to implement. Not sure what you mean by looping. My understanding is that MKOverlay does a bunch of sequential looping anyway.

Comment: By looping I meant I loop through an array of my saved coordinates that were saved in Core Data as an NSSet.  This takes a few seconds, which I don't want to make the user wait for.  I am all for saving the MKOverlay in the file system, but am confused about how to use NSCoder.  I guess if that is the route, then I need some direction on where to start.  Looked at Apples docs and still slightly confused.